# Replace one div with another on click - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have troubles with replace tag on click.

I have read some articles, but nothing.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/)

```
$('.click').click(function()){
    $('.div1').removeClass('show');
    $('.div2').addClass('show');
}
```

Do you know, what is wrong? Thank you

Comment: Your parentheses are in the wrong place.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/2/

One too many close brackets on the function. Add one at the end of the curly brace and semicolon that as well

Comment: [**Working Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/3/) ....Was a typo !!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue was a syntax error.

Comment: @codebreaker - lets try keep interactions on [so] polite. There is no need to be rude to new users. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: No intention to hurt user but the way he posted originally made me put this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    $('.click').click(function() {
            $('.div2').replaceWith($('.div1'));        
    });
```

Comment: Never mind. Please upvote it and/or mark it as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/11/)

you need to modify `class="div1 show"`
and

```
$('.click').click(function(){
      $('.div1').removeClass('show');
      $('.div2').addClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors in your javascript code

```
$('.click').click(function(){
            $('.div1').removeClass('show');
             $('.div2').addClass('show');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code - you added a bracket `)` right after `function()`

Should be -

```
$('.click').click(function(){
                  alert(1);
            $('.div1').removeClass('show');
             $('.div2').addClass('show');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/12/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting two classes for your html element in different `class` attributes, they must be set in a single `class` attribute, so replace your following code:

```
<div class="div1" class="show"></div>
```

for this one:

```
<div class="div1 show"></div>
```

Also you had bad syntax in your anonymous function, see the updated [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/15/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax issue with parenthesis. Use this:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
            $('.div1').removeClass('show');
             $('.div2').addClass('show');
})
```

Here is the update fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2 hide"></div><!-- don't use class attribute twice -->

<button class="click">Click</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.click').click(function(){ // extra parenthesis after function()
     $('.div1,.div2').toggleClass('hide'); // use toggleClass()
}); // missing parenthesis after }
```

Read [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

**CSS**

```
.hide{ /* USe hide class here */
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjhn/14/)